# How to set arbitrary environment upon starting Meteor?

Tags: meteor

So, lets say I have 4 environments

Local
Stage
Preprod
Prod

I want to set up a flag on start of local so that I can identify whether it is local or not.

I am aware of isDevelopment, but that only differentiates between prod and any development environment.

What I imagine is starting Meteor something like

```
meteor --local
```

and then having access to a global variable isLocal set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create multiple settings files.

E.g.

settings-local.json

```
{
    local: true,
}
```

settings-stage.json:

```
{
    stage: true
}
```

All you need to do then is start meteor using whichever settings file you wish to use:

```
meteor --settings settings-stage.json
```

Then in your code you can test against these

```
if (Meteor.settings.stage) { //do something }
```